# Метод выполняющийся после изменения элемента массива или списка в C#?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Можно ли и если можно то как, написать метод или `Action`, который будет срабатывать на изменения любого элемента `List`?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _изменением элемента_?

Comment: Попробуй унаследовать List и перегрузить операторы(Этот для начала https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Можно использовать [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) или [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). У них есть события `ListChanged` и `CollectionChanged` соответственно.

Comment: Можно наследоваться от `Collection` - он предоставляет специальные виртуальные методы вставки/удаления/etc, которые можно перегрузить и выполнить в них свои действия, собственно `ObservableCollection` так и делает. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov изменение коллекции и изменение объекта в коллекции далеко не тоже самое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>В примерах я использую C# 7.0, доступный в Visual Studio 2017.
 Если вы используете более ранние версии студии, адаптируйте код под вашу версию.</sub>

### Реализация [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Во-первых, элементы вашей коллекции должны реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Это не так и сложно. Допустим у нас есть класс `Credentials`, у которого есть поля `Email` и `Password`. Для него реализация будет выглядеть так:

```
public class Credentials: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _email;

    private string _password;

    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set
        {
            if (value != _email)
            {
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Email));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set
        {
            if (value != _password)
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Небольшой совет по оптимальной реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`: если у вас есть больше одного класса в проекте для которого следует реализовать этой интерфейс, то вынесите реализацию в абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Затем в этом случае реализация на примере того же класса `Credentials` будет проще:

```
public class Credentials : ObservableObject
{
    private string _email;

    private string _password;

    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set
        {
            if (value != _email)
            {
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Email));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set
        {
            if (value != _password)
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Работа с [`BindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).

Во-вторых, следует выбрать подходящую коллекцию. [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) для данной задачи **категорически не подходит**. Она не содержит никакого события для изменения самого элемента коллекции. Для этой задачи подходит `BindingList`.

Объявляем переменную/поле/свойство типа `BindingList` и подписываемся на событие `ListChanged`. Допустим у нас есть свойство только для чтения типа `BindingList`:

```
public BindingList<Credentials> CredentialsCollection { get; }
```

Где-нибудь в коде (например, в конструкторе) подписываемся на событие `ListChanged`:

```
CredentialsCollection.ListChanged += CredentialsCollection_ListChanged;
```

Определяем сам обработчик события:

```
private void LinkedInAccountViewModels_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Если у нас изменился элемент
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
        // Код для обработки изменения элемента
    }
}
```